# Is there something similar to getViewById() in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm new to `cocoa` and it seems in order to get reference to a `view/button/label/text etc..` you have to create an outlet using the interface builder. But is there some kind of mechanism like `html/android` where you can get reference to a `view/button/label/text` programmatically like `getViewById()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-[NSView viewWithTag:]` (which accepts an integer) to search the view hierarchy for the object with a tag that you have specified in Interface Builder, other code, etc.

It is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/viewWithTag%3a).

Comment: Note that this will be much slower than just having a direct reference to the object via an outlet.

Comment: Absolutely, not to mention that `[viewController myTextfield]` is much more meaningful than `[[viewController view] viewWithTag:12]`. There's also the issue of keeping the tags up to date.

Comment: You can ameliorate that with a header file full of tag names (e.g., “MyTagInputField”), but you can't use those in IB, so then you have to make sure the tag values you use in IB match the values you've named in the header—a clear DRY violation with the usual consequences.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: That's what I was getting at, w.r.t. not being able to use the header file's definitions in IB. Do you know of an actual use-case for view tags?

Comment: Closest I can think of would be stashing array indexes in them, but even that makes me feel dirty. Being able to associate a string or, better yet, any property list or even any object at all with the view would be far more useful.

Answer (score 2):

If you create the object programmatically, then you can access it by the name. Otherwise, you really do want to use outlets.

Comment: That was my next option if there wasn't something like [NSView viewWithTag:], but I wanted to use some of the layout and alignment feature of the IB.

Comment: @dpham: So? How does that block you from using outlets?